# class variable is reset each request

Tags: php, static, variables

i hava a class that hold a list for each request 
but each request the list is empty again 
what can i do to make it live

here is my class , i want the list to hold values from previews requests 
(yes each request i'm settings a value there )

```
class Sessions{
    private static $list     = array();
    ....
    .....
}
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers; they took the time to answer so you should pick the one that was the most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to be like that. Every request is independent and restarts whole program. Use sessions to store data between requests.

Comment: can i store objects in sessions ?

Comment: yes you can, as long they are serializable:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Answer (score 1):

'static' variables do not survive until the next request. You should either use $_SESSION to store custom data per user, or save it to some file/database/...

Answer (score 1):

If you want data to persist for each request from the same user you have to use session. If you want data to persist for every user you have to store them in a file or in database.